# SDK is installed and still get 'The term 'makecert' is not recognized' error

Tags: powershell, path, makecert

Running win8.1 rtm (MSDN). I've downloaded the sdk to

> 'C:\Users\foo\Downloads\Windows Kits\8.1\StandaloneSDK'.

No errors the first time I ran it ... attempting to re-run tells me all features are uptodate. I've re-booted.

Attempting to execute the makecert tool:

> makecert -sky exchange -r -n "CN=myDevLaptop" -pe -a sha1 -len 2048
>   -ss My "myDevLap.cer"

and get:

> makecert : The term 'makecert' is not recognized as the name of a
>   cmdlet, function,  script file, or operable program. Check the
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was  included, verify that the path
>   is correct and try again.

Suspect that the path's length is preventing further appendage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I'm going to need to cull my path a bit. The following explicitly entered path solved the original problem.

> set-location 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\'
>   makecert -sky exchange -r -n "CN=myDevLaptop" -pe -a sha1 -len 2048 -ss My "myDevLap.cer"